# Completion past special characters

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-tex

When I used vim for programming I used cntrl+n/cntrl+p a lot for keyword completion. I switched from programming to reporting with vim and now I have some new needs, one of which is amazing LaTeX support (huzzah vim has this).

Now I would like to keep using completion of cntrl+n and cntrl+p but past semi-colons. As I create sections and chapters with labels so I can make references to these. But a chapter label is c:name and a section is s:name where a subsection is ss:name. If I could do c: to get the previous chapter that would be great.

Does stock Vim offer this, or should I create a plug-in for this?

Comment: If the chapter, section etc. labels are in the same file, or in any other open buffers, you can still use `Ctrl-n/Ctrl-p` if you add `:` to the keyword characters: `:set iskeyword+=:`. Meaning just that, if you wrote `c:blah` somewhere, `c:` `Ctrl-n` will autocomplete that later on.

Comment: [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) offers this through an omni-complete function, see `:h 'omnifunc'` (and similar help pages). As do other LaTeX plugins for Vim, such as [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box).

Comment: @VanLaser  Perfect! Post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: ... and - done! I also recommend the `vimtex` plugin BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the chapter, section etc. labels are in the same file, or in any other open buffers, you can still use `Ctrl-n`/`Ctrl-p`. You just have to add `:` to the keyword characters, with:

```
:set iskeyword+=:
```

This enables (no more than) the following: if you write `c:blah` somewhere, `c:` followed by `Ctrl-p` (or `Ctrl-n`) is able to later offer it for autocompletion.